# Im trying to use Nativewind/Tailwind css with react native but i keep getting an error

Tags: javascript, react-native, tailwind-css, nativewind

**Started Metro Bundler
iOS Bundling failed 1903ms
App.js: C:\Users\Tomiwa Kukoyi\Desktop\infocrypto\infocrypto\App.js: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins**

**this is the error i keep getting, im using yarn, ive also used the documentation and followed everything through**

**my tailwind config file**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
  plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
};
```

**babel coonfig file**

```
{
  "name": "infocrypto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.5.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind version `3.3.3` is not working with the current version of the Nativewind(2.0.11).

- Downgrade and lock your Tailwind version to `3.3.2`:

```json
{
  "name": "infocrypto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.5.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.11",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

- Remove `node_modules` folder and `.lock` file and reinstall your npm packages.
- Run `expo start --clear` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

yarn add tailwindcss 3.3.2 --dev and restart your server
delete your node modules and delete lock file and run yarn